# How to get video meta data when the track changes in JW player 7?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

Looking through their docs, I do not see any method which allows me to get the metadata when a video changes.

I would like to get the videos metadata so I can display that data in custom way.

Comment: Does [this](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/#metadata) not do what you want?

Comment: @kemotoe kind of but it seems to be only giving me the url, i need stuff like title and whatever else i loaded into the play list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/javascript-api-reference/#jwplayeronplaylistitem

when the video changes, u get metadata back.

```
jwplayer().on('playlistItem', function(data) { console.log('meta', data.item); });
```